# Define python directory in cpanel

Tags: python, django

My Cpanel host has 2 instances of Python.

Python 2.6 - /usr/bin/python

Python 3.6 - /usr/bin/python3.6

If I run this script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html>Hello world!</html>"
```

It works!

But If it doesn't work (Internal error 500) if I run:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.6

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html>Hello world!</html>"
```

I know python 3.6 is installed and in the specified path, as you can see below:
[image]

WHEREIS
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`#! /usr/bin/python` is a **shebang line**.

A shebang line defines where the interpreter is located. In this case, the `python3` interpreter is located in `/usr/bin/python3`.

You may try using `#!/usr/bin/python3` instead of `#! /usr/bin/python3.6`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: So that's probably because your script doesn't have the executable permission yet. Try running `chmod a+x bar.py` where bar is your script name.

Comment: Thank you, Kseikyo. Unbelievable, the problem was the print function. It was on python2 style, without parentheses. It was causing the Internal Error or it was a coincidence after I ran your command. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the missing parentheses in the print function, it was python2 style and it was causing a 500 internal error.

I changed to:
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
print("Hello world!")