# How to include a python path in php codigniter controller function on cpanel

Tags: python, php, codeigniter, cpanel

I have a problem running my email script via php Codeigniter controller on cpanel although it's working perfectly fine locally using xampp. I need a Python path to include in my PHP code on cpanel.

Here is my PHP code:

```
public function forgot_password() {
     // Define email from PHP input
    $get_record = $this->request->getPost('query');
    $get_record = json_decode($get_record);
    $recipient_email = $get_record[0];  
    $register_model = new RegisterModel();
    $data_login['row']=$register_model->where('email', $recipient_email)->first();
    $password = $data_login['row']['password'];
    // Specify the path to the Python executable
    $pythonPath = 'C:\\Users\\omers\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe';

    // Path to Python script
    $pythonScript = 'var/scripts/send_email.py';

    // Execute the Python script using command-line arguments
    $command = "\"$pythonPath\" \"$pythonScript\" " . escapeshellarg($recipient_email) . " " . escapeshellarg($password);

    $output = shell_exec($command);
}
```

Here is my python script:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import sys  # Import the sys module to access command-line arguments

# Set email credentials
sender_email = "xxxxxxxxx"
sender_password = "xxxxxxxxx"

# Accept the recipient email and password as command-line arguments
if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
    recipient_email = sys.argv[1]
    recipient_password = sys.argv[2]
else:
    recipient_email = None
    recipient_password = None

if recipient_email:
    # Create the email message
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message["From"] = sender_email
    message["To"] = recipient_email
    message["Subject"] = "Credentials for MS Thesis Management System https://xxxxxxxx.com"

# Email body with password and additional message
email_body = f"Hello, {recipient_email}\n\n" \
             f"Please visit https://xxxxxxx.com, login with your NU email, " \
             f"and the password shared in this email: {recipient_password}"
message.attach(MIMEText(email_body, "plain"))

# Connect to the SMTP server
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(sender_email, sender_password)

# Send the email
server.sendmail(sender_email, recipient_email, message.as_string())

# Disconnect from the server
server.quit()
```

I am confused about what to add as a Python path in my PHP CodeIgniter app on the cpanel file manager directory, I can't find the Python path to include like this:

**$pythonPath = 'C:\Users\omers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe';**

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, but I think you are asking where Python is in your CPanel server?  I searched for "*cpanel python path*" and found plenty of things to try ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524970/define-python-directory-in-cpanel)), did you try that?  Eg `/usr/bin/python`?  In any case this seems like a question for your hosting provider, rather than SO.